# C++ HackerRank - Array Manipulation

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault

Here is the question which I am trying to solve and in the last section, I try to bring all my questions together.

I am able to pass 11 test cases but the submission complains of segmentation fault for test cases that use very large n and m. 
https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/crush/problem

The problem, in brief, expects the addition of elements in the init_array based on the elements in the queries vector.

Here is my code to solve the problem. Note: I changed data type "int" to "long unsigned int" because some of the output results were > 32,767.

```
// Complete the arrayManipulation function below.
unsigned long int arrayManipulation(unsigned long int n,
                                    vector<vector<unsigned long int>> queries) {
    unsigned long int init_array[n+1]={0};
    unsigned long int max = init_array[0];
    for(unsigned long int i=0; i<queries.size();++i)//m
    {
      for(unsigned long int j=queries.at(i).at(0); j<=queries.at(i).at(1); ++j)
      {

         init_array[j-1]+=queries.at(i).at(2);

          if(init_array[j-1] > max)
              max = init_array[j-1];
      }
    }

    return max;
}
```

One of the test cases that my code fails:

Input:

```
10000000 100000

1449932 7787270 51019
912262 3955862 23367
720355 6300425 44414
4058050 4109759 82390
630827 1992079 83163
4595878 6289869 37323
6117634 7440834 53818
3577465 5755968 89549
611287 4779893 49153
6118450 8290500 9271
6328120 8594121 59202
695492 2549982 71464
1366758 8035211 8170
5476516 5979625 82571
2378367 9984946 13398
4580824 5961530 19618
3214809 9215205 60451
1487128 5985376 37916
574925 6267020 65554
2340430 4901822 56053
749701 1229941 50173
1925432 3125256 16506
2476995 6413072 83263
972971 2937594 59778
3351338 3520166 61075
1829219 7249916 41898
1044424 7269534 73058
4729986 9546151 60185
121075 8284254 27205
2449808 2461505 29026
5727557 7422213 75318
988738 1369164 17102
7105244 7782235 94096
719829 7104859 67066
2580989 6756346 18403
4006261 8042064 47622
600315 3792146 8397
1038483 6373373 54547
3633559 9322736 91973
4288895 7160764 69829
1711107 8106142 97386
281460 5216196 66549
2321439 6898562 65136
5992658 9426297 1316
2007285 8576077 57661
2565701 4510
```

<< Please use the download link to view the full input testcase >>

Expected output:

```
2484930878
```

1. This code works for small n and m, ~ 4000 and 30000 respectively. Why do I see issues of segmentation fault with large n or m?
2. What is the complexity of the algorithm above? O(m log n) on an average? For every 'm' iterations, I run the second loop only on a subset of 'n' indices.

Comment: Probably a stack overflow. Try using `std::vector` instead of an array.

Comment: "unsigned long int init_array[n+1]={0}" there is no such thing as C Variable Length Arrays in C++

Comment: Unrelated: `vector<vector<unsigned long int>>` can be shockingly slow due to poor spatial locality. If the size of the inner dimension is known, you may find performance improvements from `vector<array<unsigned long int, SIZE>>`

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you are overflowing the stack with your init_array.  Try using a `vector` instead:

```
vector<unsigned long int> init_array(n);
```